# Deriving the radius of a circle from the area of an annulus

Tags: geometry, area

I'm really struggling to help my daughter catch up on lessons she missed and I can't find how to do this on google anywhere or in my old textbooks. The problem I'm given is that there is a ring (or annulus if I have that right). A segment of that annulus with an angle of 120 has an area of 12π. This is all the information I'm given and asked to determine the radius of the circle.

[image: problem]

I know helping with homework is usually a no no on stack exchange. Can someone at least point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Do they tell you it is an annulus?  The white region could be just to let you see the $120^\circ$ and the $12\pi$ would be the area of the sector of the circle.  That is nice because then the circle area is $36\pi$.  Otherwise you have to guess that the inner radius is half the outer radius from the picture but it doesn't come out so neatly then.

Comment: The most likely case is that the figure just shows a circle and this gives a circle with radius $6$. If it **is** an annulus the nicest answer would be $R=10, r=8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally for an annulus you would need 2 radii, the inner and the outer. If you have just one circle, here are the steps:

1. Write $120^\circ$ in radians
2. The area of the full circle (of $2\pi$ radians) would be $\pi r^2$. What is the area of your segment? (Think ratios of the angles corresponding to ratios of the areas)
3. Set your known area of $12\pi$ equal to the result of (2) and solve for $r$.

Feel free to comment below for additional guidance.

Comment: I've got a pile of sticky notes now and I feel like I'm close to getting it, but I'm going in circles (no pun intended). For your step 1, I have 2/3 radians. I'm a little unsure what you mean by ratio of angles since the annulus and circle have segments have the same angle (unless I am missing something).As for the ratio of areas, I assume you mean that the area of the same segment of the full circle is ^2 / 3 as compared to the area of 12. I'm just missing a step in there and I'm not sure what

Comment: @Daniel First of all, it is a pleasure to help a dad who wants to help his daughter. It is even more pleasure to see someone, who has his daughter by his side, trying to help you. Now, as gt6989b has pointed out in his answer, the information you have provided is not enough to solve this riddle, if it is an annulus. So, why don't you find out from your daughter, whether the given area is a part of an annulus or a disk? If this is an annulus, we need to know the radius of the inner circle in terms of the radius of the outer circle.

Comment: Ah! I think I misunderstood the answer from gt6989b. I read it as "normally you would need this info, but since you don't, you can take this approach." On a plus note, we both learned how to do a number of things we didn't know how to do in trying to solve this. She's going to have a chance to check in with her teacher today and see if there's something we're misunderstanding about the question.

Comment: Ugh. It was a poorly drawn worksheet. The white area was just so the black text would be legible. There were a million better ways to do that like white text or a box around the text. It was worse because the 3 previous problems were about finding the area of an annulus. oh well. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Daniel you are welcome, sorry to only see this now...